# update-grub Errors regarding syntax and memory

Tags: server, grub2, grub-legacy

I'm trying to configure extra boot menu options in GRUB, but I get the following error list when I use `sudo update-grub` command. How to fix this?

[image]

Note: I changed the configuration of /etc/grub.d/40_custom
Edit: 40_custom content
[image: error2]

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom` to your question.

Comment: added the output of  `sudo cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Comment: Seems there is a mistake in the last line of each menuentry, `root=UUI` should look like something like this: `root=UUID=06a41c79-a7ff-4fd2-86eb-fb4f510bf31a`. Use the same UUID which is used two lines above in each entry. In the future, please don't post screenshots of plain text, use copy and paste from terminal, this will reduce the burden on the servers and is much better to read and process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but will this modification erase multi-user.target and ssl.target booting configurations? If so, I cannot apply these changes.

Comment: No, it will just correct the syntax, try it.

Comment: Nothing has changed.

Comment: after the change you have to run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: I did, after executing this command I get exactly the same errors.

Comment: Then there is something more I don't know about. I think the correction I suggested is necessary. Just compare other menu-entries in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with your new entries and you can see what I mean. Probably this happend to you to a copy-paste mistake, can happen. I'm out of ideas, sorry that I can't help more to solve this.

Comment: In other menu-entries I see an additional line `initrd /boot/initrd.img-......`, also I miss a closing `}` as last line in your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

Comment: Great, I was sure it was a syntax problem. Enjoy life! I upvoted your question for your effort and always quick responses.